# Creating a Random number(in Class) for later extensive use in program C#

Tags: c#, class, random, numbers

I have to create a program where the player has 6 choices, between 2 pets, he must decide either to **feed, talk or play** with each one, however he can only do one at a time and each time he chooses an option the option chosen (**except when talking**) makes the other options increase while the former one decreases.

Im having trouble in all aspects, inside the program and inside the class.
I can't seem to define the random numbers inside the Class, and that makes the program not work.

### This is the code for the Class so far, here is where the problem must be happening:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Tamagochi
{
class Tamagochi
{
    private string tamagochi;
    private double hungerLvl;
    private double boredomLvl;
    private double totalLevels;
    private static int time;
    private static int RandomNumberGenerator;
    private static int ranNum1;
    private static int ranNum2;
    private static int ranNum3;
    private static int ranNum4;
    public Tamagochi (string tamagochi)
        {
        this.tamagochi = tamagochi;
        }

    public Tamagochi (string tamagochi, double hungerLvl, double boredomLvl, double randomNumbers, int RandomNumberGenerator)
    {
        this.tamagochi = tamagochi;
        this.hungerLvl = hungerLvl;
        this.boredomLvl = boredomLvl;
        this.RandomNumberGenerator = RandomNumberGenerator;

    }
    public static void IncreaseTime()
    {
        ++time;
    }
    public static void IncreaseBoredomLvl(double boredomLvl, int random)
    {
        boredomLvl += // randomnumber
    }
    public static void IncreaseHungerLvl(double hungerLvl)
    {
        hungerLvl += //randomnumber
    }
    public static void randomNumber(int min, int max)
    {
        Random RandomNumberGenerator = new Random();
        ranNum1 = RandomNumberGenerator.Next(1, 6);
        ranNum2 = RandomNumberGenerator.Next(1, 6);
        ranNum3 = RandomNumberGenerator.Next(1, 6);
        ranNum4 = RandomNumberGenerator.Next(1, 6);

    }


    //return section

    public string GetTamagochi()
    {
        return tamagochi;
    }
    public double GetBoredomLvl()
    {
        return boredomLvl;
    }
    public double GetHungerLvl()
    {
        return hungerLvl;
    }
    public static int GetTime()
    {
        return time;

    }
    public static int GetRandomNum()
    {
        return ranNum1;
    }
}
}
```

Any help on trying to make this work?

Comment: Don't create the `Random` instance in the method `randomNumber`, instead either pass it via method parameter or use a field in the class. Otherwise it's likely that you get the same numbers if you call this method in a loop because the `Random`-constructor uses the current time as seed.

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve], and make sure you describe the actual problem you're running into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The Random number should be declared outside the function.
- The seed should be effective.
- If you want a number between 1 and 6 (both including) you should put in the Next() function from 1 to 7 (because 7 is not included)

So, Your code should look like this:

```
class Tamagochi
{

    private int ranNum1;
    private int ranNum2;
    private int ranNum3;
    private int ranNum4;
    Random RandomNumberGenerator;

    public Tamagochi()
    {
        RandomNumberGenerator = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
    }
    public void GetRandomNumber()
    {
        ranNum1 = RandomNumberGenerator.Next(1,7);
        ranNum2 = RandomNumberGenerator.Next(1,7);
        ranNum3 = RandomNumberGenerator.Next(1,7);
        ranNum4 = RandomNumberGenerator.Next(1,7);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i completely changed it now so that the Random number may be generated in the Program and I got it to work.
`code            tamagochi1.DecreaseBoredomLvl(ranNum1);
                         tamagochi1.IncreaseHungerLvl(ranNum2);
                         tamagochi2.IncreaseBoredomLvl(ranNum3);
                         tamagochi2.IncreaseHungerLvl(ranNum4);`
i then edited it with "random" as a parameter in the class

However, thanks for your help, i'm sure i will use it soon anyways.